# PHP Regex URL until a space, \ or " not returning what I need

Tags: php, regex

I am having trouble creating a regex in PHP whereby I need to extract all URLs beginning like

```
http://hello.hello/asefaesasef my name is 
https://aw3raw.com/asdfase/
www.aer.com/afseaegfefsesef\
domain.com/afsegaesga"
```

I need to basically extract the URL until I hit a white space, a backslash (`\`) or a double quote (`"`).

I have the following code:

```
$column = "adsfahttp://hello.hello/asefaesas\"ef asefa aweoija weeij asd sa https://aw3raw.com/asdfase/ asdafewww.aer.com/afseaegfefsesef\ even ashafueh domain.com/afsegaesga\"asdfasda";
preg_match_all("/(http|https):\/\/\S+[^(\"|\\)]+/",$column,$urls);
echo "Url = \n";
print_r($urls);
```

So I need my to extract so I have:

```
http://hello.hello/asefaesasef
https://aw3raw.com/asdfase
www.aer.com/afseaegfefsesef
domain.com/afsegaesga
```

I'm struggling to get my head around it as my result is showing as:

```
Url =
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => http://hello.hello/asefaesas"ef asefa aweoija weeij asd sa https://aw3raw.com/asdfase/ asdafewww.aer.com/afseaegfefsesef\ even ashafueh domain.com/afsegaesga
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => http
    )

)
```

Comment: How do you know "domain.com/afsegaesga" is a url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you've got the syntax of character classes wrong.  Within the square brackets, you don't need parentheses for grouping or pipes for alternation. Just list the characters you're interested in--or in this case, that you want to exclude.

What you're doing now is matching some non-whitespace characters (including `\` and `"`), *followed by* some not-quote, non-backslash characters (including whitespace).  You need to combine both criteria into one negated character class:

```
preg_match_all("~https?://[^\"\s\\\\]+~", $column, $urls);
```

Notice that this only matches the URLs starting with `http://` or `https://`.  You can' make the protocol optional (`"~(?:https?://)?[^\"\s\\\\]+~"`), but then the regex will match almost anything, making it useless.  Are all your URLs at the beginning of a line, the way you showed them?  If so, you can use an anchor instead:

```
preg_match_all('/(?m)^[^\"\s\\\\]+/', $column, $urls);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a `\s` to your regex: `/(http|https):\/\/\S+[^(\"|\\)\s]+/` so it doesn't match a whitespace.